# Get value of ASP.NET TextBox on Async Postback

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, textbox, updatepanel, postback

I'm using an UpdatePanel to asynchronously update a control on my ASP.NET page.  During the postback, I'd like to get the value of a TextBox control. The value I get, however, is always the original text value of the TextBox, not the text the user has inputted.  How can I get the updated value of the TextBox server-side on a postback?

Thanks in advance for any advice you have to offer.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="GridUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="AdminGridView" runat="server"
            onrowcreated="AdminGridView_RowCreated" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Grid" Font-Size="100%" 
            BorderColor="Black" oninit="AdminGridView_Init">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:TextBox ID="SortLabel" runat="server" Text="Recipients"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="DirectionLabel" Text="DESC" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**--EDIT--**

I should add that I'm attempted to retrieve the value of the TextBox in the _Init() Event in the GridView - maybe there's a better place to retrieve the value of the TextBox?

Comment: is the textbox inside the updatepanel that generated the postback?

Comment: Yes, the TextBox I'm trying to access is inside the UpdatePanel that's being called.

Comment: Could you please paste some code? I wonder if you reset the value of the textbox somewhere, for instance on page_load.

Comment: I posted the .aspx code - I don't touch the TextBox anywhere else, except to retrieve its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the updated value of your TextBox on `Init` event. This event is executed too early on the page life cycle, before page controls are set with posted values. Why don't you do it on `Button1` click?

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) MSDN article may help you to understand the asp.net page life cycle

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I moved some logic around to different events and can now access the values when they're needed.  Thanks!